# Google Test(gtest) iOS signing error

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, googletest

Following this tutorial:[Introduction to Google Test with Xcode 6 and C++11](http://bitrage.de/wp/google-test-with-xcode-6-and-c11/#comment-82) i have integrated Google Test(or gtest) framework into my iOS project written in C++. But when i choose test target and press "Run" button i got this log:"Message from debugger: Terminated due to code signing error". This log appears after "Build Succeeded" popup. If anyone has thoughts of how to fix this siging error please let me know.  (P.S. i have valid iOS certificate and provision profile and can upload builds to the TestFlight)

Answer (score 0):

I have got rid of this issue by performing next actions:

1. Select **Tests** target as active target.
2. Go to **Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme**.
3. From the left menu choose **Run**.
4. Then in the right menu choose **Info** tab.
5. Change **Build Configuration** from **Debug** to **Release**.

After this i can run tests without "signing error":))